# iPhone: XMPP Jabber client Error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xmpp, chat

I want to develop chat Application using XMPP. I studied using the following web URL: [building-a-jabber-client-for-ios](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/)

After Finishing I am successfully integrate. But This Application crashed with following Screen shot.  Kindly help me.

[Screen shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn4bd.png)